# How to handle HTTP 403 with Spring Security 3.0.x

Tags: security, spring, spring-security

I'm facing a little issue with Spring Security 3.0.x (3.0.2 in particular at the moment). The whole application I'm working on is working perfectly except when someone who doesn't have the authorities tries to log on.

When it occurs, the users is redirected to the "welcome" page, since his username/password are valid, and he receive a cute white page with this : "Error 403: Access is denied"

So, I've been looking on the net trying to find how this behavior can be handled. So far I've come to the conclusion, please correct me if I'm wrong, that it is managed by the [ExceptionTranslationFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html). But I don't quite understand how to make any good use of this information.

I've tryied to edit my SecurityContext.xml to add a **access-denied-handler** tag to my **http** tag, but it doesn't work. Do I need to add more than this tag to make it work? Is there any other possibilities to make my application more user-friendly?

**Edit** : I would like to redirect to a page, let's says 403.html, for example.

Sincerly, 
Thanks

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: How do you use the tag? Do you use something like this?: <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/controllerUrl" /> and in your controller you have a controllerUrl which returns to the view for 403.html

Comment: I use it this way : <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="${access.denied.url}" />

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found how to do this. By implementing the [AccessDeniedHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandler.html) interface and the corresponding handle method I can, easily, control the way the Http 403 error is handled.

This way, you can add various items in the session and then intercept them on your jsp.

The xml file then looks like this :

```
<sec:http>
    <!-- lots of urls here -->
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
    <sec:anonymous/>
</sec:http>

<bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="foo.bar.CustomAccessDeniedHandler">
    <property name="accessDeniedUrl" value="403.html" />
</bean>
```

The java class :

```
package foo.bar;
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler {
private String accessDeniedUrl;

    public CustomAccessDeniedHandler() {
    }

    public CustomAccessDeniedHandler(String accessDeniedUrl) {
        this.accessDeniedUrl = accessDeniedUrl;
    }

    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendRedirect(accessDeniedUrl);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("CustomSessionAttribute", "value here");
    }

    public String getAccessDeniedUrl() {
        return accessDeniedUrl;
    }

    public void setAccessDeniedUrl(String accessDeniedUrl) {
        this.accessDeniedUrl = accessDeniedUrl;
    }
}
```

And a jsp example :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
 <c:if test="${!empty CustomSessionAttribute}">
    <br/>
    ACCESS IS DENIED
    <br/>
 </c:if>
<!-- other stuff down here -->
```

Comment: You don't need to implement a custom handler

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm not saying that this is the only way of doing it, but I'm saying that this is a way that works. Also keep in mind that this is related to Spring Security 3.0.2 and that this question is 2 years old. Things might have changed by now.

Comment: When I found this page (was looking for 403 interception) your answer and the other answer had the same rating, but yours was marked as the correct answer. As you said, the question is 2 years old, but people looking for a solution will prefer the other answer. It does not mean yours is bad.

Answer (score 23):

I still don't get why you had to implement your own access handler... I have currently faced same task:

```
 <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied"/> - works like charm.
```

Don't forget to specify handler in your Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/accessDenied")
      public String accessDenied() {

            return "accessDenied"; // logical view name
       }
```

**Update for Spring Boot(2014 Oct):**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(customHandler) OR .accessDeniedPage("/somePage.html").and
            .formLogin()
                .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)}
```

Nowadays we don't really return views for such task since angular js kicks in so you can use your failure/success handler and return tailored JSON responses. For us it was sufficient to use failure handler but you get to choose where you want your control to kick in. We generally don't use view resolvers as there are UI tiles frameworks(such as angular partials) able to construct pieces into single page for you. Html pieces are stored on the server and served simply as static resources.

**Lets play with Embedded Tomcat to achieve similar behavior to web.xml !**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.profiles(addDefaultProfile())
            .showBanner(false)
            .sources(Application.class);
}

//required for container customizer to work, the numerous tutorials didn't work for me, so I simply tried overriding the default one
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    return tomcat;
}

@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer(

) {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
             containerFactory.setSessionTimeout(1); // just for your interest, remove as necessary

            containerFactory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,"/views/accessDenied.html"),
                    new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,"/views/notFound.html"));
            containerFactory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
                @Override
                public void customize(Connector connector) {
                    connector.setPort(8082);// just for your interest, remove as necessary
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: This is the best solution as defining an error page in `web.xml` will not provide user access to spring security tags in JSP views, like a template page resulting in seemingly missing content (i.e. menus, username etc...).

Answer (score 9):

A cleaner way to handle error redirects is to use the `<error-page>` and `<error-code>` tags in your web.xml. See below for an example:

```
<!-- Custom 403 Error Page -->
<!--
            NOTE: Security will throw this error when a user has been authenticated successfully
            but lacks the permissions to perform the requested action.
    -->
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/403.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

This block of code will redirect to the specified location whenever it encounters the specified error code.

This eliminates the need for authorization code inside your application logic.

Comment: This will work, though you will not have access to the `Authentication` object, so any `http://www.springframework.org/security/tags` tags being used will not be accessible resulting in everything within these tags not appearing.

Comment: This is entirely true and it is good that you pointed it out for future readers. The best strategy depends entirely on how people want their application to handle authentication errors. If you want to do some sort of processing of information when someone fails to authenticate then its true that this solution won't work due to the point you stated. If you just want to send the user to a cookie-cutter access-denied page, then I like using this solution because it doesn't get mixed in with the rest of my application code.

Comment: @KristenD. Could you please state, how the **location** of the error page facelet should be set? My pages are not redirected. Is that a relative path in the `webapp` folder? Are in your case error pages placed directly in that folder? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The way to make this work is to define a handler in your entry point:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (authException != null) {
            // you can check for the spefic exception here and redirect like this
            response.sendRedirect("403.html");
        }
    }
}
```

You can define this as your entry point by setting this as you entry point in the xml config file:

```
<http entry-point-ref="customAuthenticationEntryPoint">

  ...

</http>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have checked the  tag in an application and to me it seems to work.

```
<sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/handle403Url" />
```

where handle403Url I want to call to handle this error (for example to show an error).

Don't forget that you have to allow this url in the filters so it can be reached by this user authority, so in the start of the flters you have to add something like this:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/handle403Url" filters="none" />
```