# Handling AccessDenied with Method Level Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

i have a method secured with spring security as follows:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('add_user')")
public void addUser(User user) ;
```

and if a user with no enoguh permissions is trying to invoke it 
, an accessDenied exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

this is what's expected, but the question is, why the defined **access-denied-handler**

in security.xml configuration file is **not working**:

```
<access-denied-handler error-page="accessDenied"/>
```

**I mean by not working** that when user with not enough permission when trying to press the button addUser which will invoke the service addUser (that's only accessible by user has this permission) an AccessDenied Exception is thrown and that's the desired behavior, but the user isn't redirected to the access denied exception as configured in xml.

shouldn't the user gets redirected automatically to access denied page when this exception is thrown, or i have to define such behavior explicitly in code ?

please advise.

I am using **Spring Security 3.0.5** with **JSF 2.1** and **ICEFaces 2**

**UPDATE:** applicationSecurity.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.4.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">


        <!-- Enable @pre, @post spring security method level annotations -->
        <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />   


        <http use-expressions="true"  auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied">

     <session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>

        <remember-me  token-validity-seconds="1209600"/>


        <intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied" access="permitAll"/>        
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll" />


        <intercept-url pattern="/faces/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/xmlhttp/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />        
        <intercept-url pattern="/scripts/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />


        <!-- All pages requires authentication (not anonymous user) -->

        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/faces/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />


        <form-login default-target-url="/"   
        always-use-default-target="true"            
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"         
            login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1"                                                               
        />

        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login" />     
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">          
      <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl"/>    
    </authentication-manager>


    </beans:beans>
```

**UPDATE 2** : debugs before exception:

```
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.java:93) - @org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize(value=hasRole('add_user')) found on specific method: public void com.myapp.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.addUser(com.myapp.domain.User) throws java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.java:66) - Adding security method [CacheKey[com.myapp.service.impl.UserServiceImpl; public abstract void com.myapp.service.UserService.addUser(com.myapp.domain.User) throws java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException]] with attributes [[authorize: 'hasRole('add_user')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:191) - Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public abstract void com.myapp.service.UserService.addUser(com.myapp.domain.User) throws java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException; target is of class [com.myapp.service.impl.UserServiceImpl]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'hasRole('add_user')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:292) - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@c650d918: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@db344023: Username: user@mycomp.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: access_viewUsers; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: E6BBAC0CD4499B1455227DC6035CC882; Granted Authorities: access_viewUsers
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (AffirmativeBased.java:53) - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@1d1e082e, returned: -1
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (AffirmativeBased.java:53) - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@1eab12f1, returned: 0
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (AffirmativeBased.java:53) - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@71689bf1, returned: 0
```

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186697/how-to-handle-http-403-with-spring-security-3-0-x gives some clues?

Comment: this example made custom implementation, since he wants to add extra data to session when access denied occurs, i don't need this customization, i just need the default behavior.

Comment: Please post the complete security configuration.

Comment: @fresh_dev: what do you mean exactly by "not working"?

Comment: @Ralph, question updated with explaining the not working case.

Comment: @fresh_dev: I still not understand what "not working" mean. I mean what happen instead of "but the user isn't redirected to the access denied exception as configured in xml."? -- knowing this would be a great indicator of what is going wrong.

Comment: @Ralph , what's happening is that when use with not enough permission trying to invoke protected method, an AccessDeniedException is thrown but the user is not redirected to the accessDenied page specified either with accessDenied attribute or with access denied handler as in one of the answers down.

Comment: No, it is still not clear, if there is the exception, is then the exception printet in the browser?

Comment: after i used the accessDeniedHandler, it's thrown in both console and in the xhtml page which the user was trying to access with not enough permission, but before using that it was thrown in console only.

Comment: @fresh_dev: not really only a hint how I would start to find the problem.

Answer (score 4):

According to the spring Security documentation the user of the access-denied-page attribute of the  element has been deprecated in Spring 3.0 and above.

We do the following in our app:

1. Create a custom access denied handler by extending the Spring Security framework's `AccessDeniedHandlerImpl`.
2. Call the `setErrorPage` method, passing in the name of the controller that will display your access denied page
3. In our case we lock the user's account in the custom handler - there's no good reason for any user to ever get an access denied exception unless they're doing something that they should't.  We also log what they were trying to access, etc.
4. Call `super.handle(_request, _response, _exception);` at the end of the handler.  Spring will forward control to the controller listed in #2 above.

   ```
   public class AccessDeniedHandlerApp extends AccessDeniedHandlerImpl {
       private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AccessDeniedHandlerApp.class);

       private static final String LOG_TEMPLATE = "AccessDeniedHandlerApp:  User attempted to access a resource for which they do not have permission.  User %s attempted to access %s";

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServletRequest _request, HttpServletResponse _response, AccessDeniedException _exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
            setErrorPage("/securityAccessDenied");  // this is a standard Spring MVC Controller

            // any time a user tries to access a part of the application that they do not have rights to lock their account
            <custom code to lock the account>
            super.handle(_request, _response, _exception);
   }
   ```

   }

Here's my XML: `AccessDeniedHandlerApp` extends 'AccessDeniedHandlerImpl`

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/views/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/Login.jsp" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessFilter"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginFailureFilter" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/home" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="customAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="customAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.demo.security.AccessDeniedHandlerApp"/>
```

Here's my Access Denied Controller - I should have posted this earlier - sorry about that.  In order to get the access denied page to come up I had to use a redirect:

```
@Controller
public class AccessDeniedController {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AccessDeniedController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/securityAccessDenied")
    public String processAccessDeniedException(){
        logger.info("Access Denied Handler");
        return "redirect:/securityAccessDeniedView";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/securityAccessDeniedView")
    public String displayAccessDeniedView(){
        logger.info("Access Denied View");
        return "/SecurityAccessDenied";
    }
```

Please let me know if this doesn't resolve it and I'll keep digging - I just tested it again locally here and this should do the trick.
    }

Comment: well above code doesn't work with me, accessDeniedException is thrown, but user is not redirected to the access denied page !!!

Comment: @jcurtin it doesn't work for me too, exception is thrown, but user is not redirected to the custom access denied handler ref, any ideas why ?

Comment: @fresh_dev  - did that help you guys out?

Comment: as i told you before, it doesn't enter in the AccessDeniedHandlerApp class in first place, this is the key issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem myself and posted another question relating to the same issue.  After several hours of digging around, I finally found the solution for my issue.  I know this question is 2+ years old, but thought I would update it with information in case it was of value to someone else.

In a nutshell, I noticed that the `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` was handling the exception and resolving it with a default mapping.  Consequently, there was no exception left to bubble up the stack to the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` which would redirect to the `access-denied-handler`.

Please see [Spring Security ignoring access-denied-handler with Method Level Security](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21171882/827480) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security redirect to the access denied page just when the user don't have authorization to access the resource. This is, when the user is authenticated but doesn't have the allowed roles.

But when the problem is not authorization, but authentication, Spring Security redirects to the login page (to let the user authenticate himself/herself), not to the access denied page.

As you have a rule checking for "isAuthenticated()" in the rules, you won't be redirected to the access denied page, but to the login page.

Hope it helps.